# Why does my script searching for a certain word in a database always print out "None" as a result? I am using the mysql.connector for python34

Tags: python, mysql

My code:

```
import mysql.connector as sqlc

cnx = sqlc.connect(user='', password='',host='', database='dictionary')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM dictionary"

print(cursor.execute(sql))
```

As a result I am allways getting None. It doesnt matter if I am searching for a specific word or even want to print out the whole database it's allways None

```
None
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

I am a hundred percent certain the searched word is in the database and even tried it out in php and was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute(sql)` executes the query; to get the results, use `cursor.fetchall()`. This will return a list with all the results, and will return an empty list if no results are retrieved. You can loop through this list normally to print out the results.

Check out [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) link that describes `fetchall()`, and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) for a general overview of MySql queries. In short, you were executing the query, but you weren't retrieving the actual results.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem